# PHP Post on multiple facebook wall

Tags: facebook, post

Well, I am developing an online web application that will interact with Facebook user pages. In my application users will join and add their facebook pages, then timely (on a daily basis) if there is some update - a picture and some text will be posted on their pages.

I have these things almost done, however, need some expert advices on how to post on walls in case there are 1000-10000 users pages registered with my application ? Will a simple loop with checking the permission etc and existence be enough ? OR do I need to take some thing else in account ?

Best Regards
ZH

Comment: Done it my self. I thought that StackOverFlow is good.